# How do I write an Gherkin test with a feature that requires a lot of input and has a lot of output?

Tags: automated-tests, bdd, gherkin

I'm quite new to Gherkin and struggling with my first project. Basically we have a lot of input parameters that are required for a fancy calculator to help people figure out if they can afford a mortgage.

Am I best off focusing on one part of the output and only specifying the input required for that input, or listing every input as a separate Given/And? e.g.

```
Scenario: Calculate loan amount and LVR
    Given the user is on the purchase calculator page
    And has filled in the rest of the calculator fields
    And entered $450,000 as their purchase price
    And entered $100,000 as their savings
    When the user submits the calculator
    Then the calculator will display the loan amount of $350,000
    And an LVR of 77.78%
```

OR

```
Scenario: calculate Homeloan affordability
    Given the user is on the Calculator page
    And the user has entered 21 Fake Street as the purchase property
    And the user entered $450,000 as their purchase price
    And the user entered $100,000 as their savings
    And the user has selected that there are two applicants
    And the user has selected two dependants
    And the user has entered $1000 monthly expences
    And...
    And...
    When the user clicks Calculate
    Then the calculator will display the loan amount of $350,000
    And an LVR of 77.78%
    And a predicted interest rate of 4.3%
    And display a google street view image of the property they have selected
    And...
    And...
```

The first one makes WAY more sense, is way easier to read, and tests one specific part of the feature, so it seams like a no-brainer. But how do I write it and cover all of the required (but not important for this test) info that fills in "And has filled in the rest of the calculator fields"?

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I am forced to disagree with the previous response.  The best way to use Gherkin is by example.  We should be explicit, never implicit.  There are some fantastic books on the subject including "Specification by Example" and "Writing Great Specifications" that explain it much better than I can here.  Here is how I would write them:

```
Scenario: Calculate loan amount and Loan to Value Ratio
   Given the user has filled in the purchase calculator information
      | Purchase Price | Savings  | 
      | $450,00        | $100,000 |
   When the user submits the calculator
   Then the calculator will display the loan details
      | Total Loan | LVR    |
      | $350,000   | 77.78% |
```

Even better, you could use a scenario outline

```
Scenario Outline: Calculate loan amount and Loan to Value Ratio
   Given the user has filled in the <purchase-price> and <savings> calculator information
   When the user submits the calculator
   Then the calculator will display the <total-loan> and <lvr>
   And the message bar will display <message>

Examples:
      | Purchase Price | Savings  | Total Loan | LVR    | Message              |
      | $450,000       | $100,000 | $350,000   | 77.78% |  OK                  |
      | $500,000       | $0       | $500,000   | 100%   |  OK                  |
      | $100,000       | $50,000  | $50,000    | 50%    |  OK                  |
      | $100,000       | $49,999  |  $0        | 0%     | Insufficient savings |
```

Notice how the example includes

1. Sunny Day scenario
2. Boundary condition(s)
3. Error condition

You can even have multiple sets of examples.  You could have one set of examples like the above that focuses on the minimum for acceptance criteria-- the minimum you need to get approval from your very busy product owner.  Then you include extra examples for thorough testing in a separate example set.  Lots of possibilities.

To answer your second question-- do you always include *all* the data fields in your example table?   The answer is no.  You include data fields that matter.  The data fields that actually affect the answer must be included.  Extra data should be removed.  You can also summarize-- for example rather than including the full address, if the location of the loan applicant matters, consider just using zip code. You can still have a full address in the code.

If the data all matters, and it is very lengthy, then I would do the following: sub-divide the test cases into categories.  For each category, just a few of the data fields will change, and the rest will be constant.  Put the ones that are constant in a `Background` section  above the scenario.  If you name the categories carefully, this can be quite readable and maintainable even for very complex/large sets of data fields.

This site documents Gherkin pretty well: http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html

Answer (score 1):

**What I would do:**

In this scenario, I would set up some dummy test data in the back end, to be able to test this properly, JSON format, or a standard data type (map or object) to compliment my scenario:

```
Scenario: Calculating Home Loan Affordability
  Given the user is on the Calculator page
  When the user has entered in their details
  And the user submits the calculator
  Then the user should receive the correct Home Loan information
```

In my test data:

```
{
homeLoanAffordability: {
     addressToBuy: "21 Fake Street",
     purchasePrice: "$450,000",
     savings: "$100,000"
     applicants: 2,
     dependants: 2,
     ...
     loanAmount: "$350,000",
     LVR: "77.78%"
   }
}
```

You could even put these in a table if you haven't got a technical background.

**Things to note**

What you're testing here really does matter though. If you are testing that specific combination (as it is an edge case), then you may want to leave it verbose, but if instead you are checking simply whether the calculator works, go with the shorter one. Also be aware that with your scenario, if any of the other data could lead to a different outcome: i.e *one dependant leads to a greater loan amount*, *one applicant leads to a lesser loan amount*, then you may want to remove the data completely from your scenario, which is what I did in my example.

**Under the hood** *If you are developing tests with a cucumber based framework*

You could write a function that takes the test data in json/standard data type form, using that as your way to do the calculations:

```
function checkHomeLoanAffordability(homeLoanObject){
  // Fill out information
  // Put end information into standard data type
  // return end information
}
```

Which (in JavaScript at least) could be used like:

```
let actualHomeLoan = calculateHomeLoan(homeLoanObject),
    testHomeLoan = testData.homeLoanAffordability;

// Using chai.expect
expect(actualHomeLoan.loanAmount).to.equal(testHomeLoan.loanAmount);
```

If you need your developers to know what the specific scenarios are, give them the test data you'll be using or show them the tests under the hood.